# Map wordpress post from array

Tags: javascript

So I have the following function:

```
/**
 * Get array of post objects
 *
 * @param slug
 */
function get_array_of_post_objects(slug)
{
    let items = [];
    wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
        const Posts = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
            url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/' + slug,
        });
        const all_posts = new Posts();
        all_posts.fetch().then((posts) => {
            items.push(...posts.items);
        });
    });
    return items;
}
```

When invoked like this:

```
const test = get_array_of_post_objects('application_launcher');
console.log(test);
```

Gives me an `array of objects` as shown below:
[image]

---

Question:

What would be a good way to map my objects? Let's say that I want to map just the `ID` and `db_id`.. what's a good approach? I haven't messed with mapping too much, so have some learning to do.

Here is what I was messing with:

```
const test2 = test.map((ID, db_id) => {
    return {
        ID,
        DBID: db_id,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you would do it like so:

```js
const test = [
      {ID:1, db_id: 11, test: 'test'},
      {ID:2, db_id: 22, test: 'test'},
      {ID:3, db_id: 33, test: 'test'}
    ];
    const test2 = test.map((obj) => {
      return {ID: obj.ID, DBID: obj.db_id};
    });

    console.log(test2);
```

A callback for the `map` function takes each element of the array as the first param.

Comment: Would I first have to loop through the array of objects? I'm getting an empty array response.

Comment: It should work as long as your `test` variable is a valid non-empty array. Updated my answer so you can test it. Based on the code in your `get_array_of_post_objects` function it may be running asynchronously and return an empty array.